# Getting an error when creating a create a Completely Randomized Design (CRD) layout in R

Tags: r, random, statistics, experimental-design

I am trying to create a Completely Randomized Design (CRD) layout in R using the `agricolae` package. The design involves 8 treatments, each replicated 6 times. However, I encountered an error while executing the code.

Here is my code:

```
# Install and load the agricolae package
install.packages("agricolae")
library(agricolae)

# Define treatments and replicates
treatments <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H")
replicates <- 1:6

# Create the CRD layout
layout <- design.crd(treatments, replicates)

# Print the layout
print(layout)

# Plot the layout
plot(layout)
```

The error I received is: `Error in data. Frame(trt, r) : arguments imply differing number of rows: 8, 6. It seems that the number of rows for treatments and replicates is not matching`.

As a workaround, I was able to create the layout using the expand.grid() function, like this:

```
# Define treatments and replicates
treatments <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H")
replicates <- 1:6

# Generate the design matrix
design <- expand.grid(Treatment = treatments, Replicate = replicates)
```

However, I'm unsure how to `plot` the expand.grid object to produce a plot like the following (it's just an example)

[image]

Could someone please help me resolve the issue with `agricolae` package `OR` guide me on how to plot the layout using the `expand.grid` object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The replicate term in `design.crd()` is not the name of the replicate by the number of desired replicates.
In this case, I am assuming you are looking for 6 replicates per treatment therefore the correct form of the function is:

```
design.crd(treatments, r=6)
```

If you would like to vary the number of replicates for each treatment then you need a vector equal to length of treatments.

```
design.crd(treatments, r=c(2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 6))
```

Comment: Thanks for the assistance. I have got the layout running your code. How can I make a sketch of the layout?

Comment: I am not familiar with plotting the designs